# How to navigate from view to another in swiftui using a button instead of navigationview

Tags: swiftui

How can i navigate from view to another using a button instead of using NavigationView or a sheet.

kind regards

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate" then?

Comment: i would have a button that takes me to another whole view instead of using NavigationView. i tried NavigationButton but it got deprecated and don't want to display the view in a sheet. thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
you cannot navigate without navigationview, but you can hide navigationbar if you want to.

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var navigate = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("aha"), isActive: self.$navigate) {
                    EmptyView().hidden()
                }.frame(height:0)
                Button(action: {
                    self.navigate = true
                }) {
                    Text("go")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really there is no other way to implement the same thing in a button ? 
Please i need more details about the SceneDelegate, i think the whole app is just a single scene to display views in a structured way (NavigationView)
thanks for your reply